# how to access a CCSprite's NSString file name

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsstring

Given a `CCSprite` how can I access the `NSString` file name for the sprite? For example if

```
CCSprite* sprite;
```

then some method or getter to return `sprite` NSString file name.

Comment: Keeping a file name may not make much sense. Consider a sprite that was constructed from a sprite frame, or even a texture, or a cropped area in a texture ... or or or. What is your purpose with the file name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way out of the box to do this. CCSprite, like any instance will not keep around much in way of the names and humanly readable stuff once the code is compiled.

It is however quite common in Cocos2D-programming to subclass the CCSprite class to add some additional properties (like points for enemies etc.) If you create your own SpriteClass you could add an NSString property "name" which you could set whenever you create a sprite. e.g.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithTexture:someTexture name:@"sprite"];
```

To make it robust you should probably create versions of all included initMethods with the name parameter added and raise an exception if nil is passed in.

Despite this being close to a solution to your problem, I would still recommend against doing it.  It's not particularly elegant and string-checks are prone to typing mistakes etc. If I was you I'd really try to find some other way to identify your sprites.

Perhaps if you told us a bit more about what you want to achieve we could find a better solution?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I need to do this mainly because I am saving the `CCSprite` using `NSCoding` (subclassed) and I'm also reusing the `CCSprite`'s and hence need to know the exact image when I save my object's state. The only properties I need for the subclass for `NSCoding` are the postition and the file name. Do you know any other way I can work around this?

Comment: So you're not really looking for the sprite-name, then, rather the name of the image? If so, I believe that is actually a public property on CCSpriteFrame for just this thing...

Comment: but that's for CCSpriteFrame, how about CCSprite?

Comment: Aren't the images you display in you sprite CCSpriteFrames?

Comment: okay I get it.  `sprite.displayFrame.textureFilename`. Thanks

Comment: I am logging the textureFilename and getting null.

Comment: Very odd. Null in particular, it should at least be nil(!) I suggest you post a new question with this concrete problem and include a juicy code snippet around where you're trying to access the textureFileName.

Comment: Please take a look at the post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896731/custom-object-with-ccsprite-that-conforms-to-nscoding-not-displaying